# when using vs2013,Failed to parse manifest; but worked well on vs2010

Tags: parsing, visual-studio-2013, manifest, application-cache

recently, My company need me to do something on application cache, and I read this article:  http://www.codemag.com/Article/1112051, I followed his steps,but it cannot work by using vs2013, it will show you the right page, but when you press f12 in chrome, it will show some error:Application Cache Error event: "Failed to parse manifest  localhost:xxxxx/Home/manifest", and actually app cache didn't work. but when I use vs2010 it works just fine! since vs2013 has a lot more files in the mvc project, I cannot figure out what's wrong.  Now I need some vs2013 tools which are not included in vs2010, so I really need the vs2013 version of this app cache program. It's quite in a hurry, can anyone help me? thanks a lot!

Comment: The manifest file is either not being generated at all, or Visual Studio looks for it in the wrong place. Check that the name and path for the manifest file matches between Solution Properties | Linker | Manifest File and Solution | Properties | Manifest Tool. You might also be able to temporarily work around the issue by turning off Solution | Properties | Manifest Tool | Input and Output | Embed Manifest, though that might cause trouble running the app.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to see if it helps.

Step 1: Run Windows System File Checker("sfc /scannow")

It allows you to scan for file corruption and restore Windows system files such as DebuggerProxy.dll. If System File Checker finds a problem with DebuggerProxy.dll or other critical system file, it will attempt to replace the problematic files from DLL Cache (%WinDir%\System32\Dllcache). If the DebuggerProxy.dll file is not in the DLL Cache, or the DLL Cache is corrupted, you will be prompted to insert the Windows installation disc to recover the original files.

To run System File Checker:

1.Click the Start button.
2.Type "cmd" in the search box... DO NOT hit ENTER yet!
3.While holding CTRL-Shift on your keyboard, hit ENTER.
4.You will be prompted with a permission dialog box.
5.Click Yes.
6.A black box will open with a blinking cursor.
7.Type "sfc /scannow" and hit ENTER.
8.System File Checker will begin scanning for DebuggerProxy.dll and other system file problems (be patient - the system scan may take a while).
9.Follow the on-screen commands.
Step 2:Make sure your ISO installation file is correct.

You can download the ISO file from the website below.

[http://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=40787]](http://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=40787%5d)

Before you install it, I suggest you use this tool http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290 to verify hash of the ISO. Any discrepancy would indicate that the file was corrupted. Here is a blog about how to use the tool.

The sha1 value of ISO is "E61419E51F42254EE07DECF628B85C9861286250".

Then try reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks for answering! but I don't think there's anything wrong with my system files. And what's more, the app can actually find the manifest file, but cannot parse it.